# Python 2.6: Unicode issue when writing to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.6

Using an extremely old version of Python (2.6), I'm running into Unicode encoding issues when writing data to a file:

```
t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode = "w+b")
res = text.encode("UTF-8")
t.write(res)
print t.read()
```

In this simple example, `text` is a `<unicode>` type.  I convert it to a `<str>` type encoded in UTF-8, and write it to an output file.  However, when I read in the file, the data is completely corrupted, indicating that some kind of encoding error is occurring.

With later versions of Python (Python 2.7), this works perfectly.  What exactly is different about Python 2.6 that causes this issue?

Comment: add `t.seek(0)` before the `repr(t.read())` (`t.flush()` wouldn't hurt though `t.seek` should be enough). Add `t.close()`. *"What exactly is different about Python 2.6 that causes this issue?"* -- try to minimize the `text` to a minimum (one or two Unicode codepoints) e.g., using a binary search (text = text[:len(text)//2], etc) or use `diff`, `cmp` to compare the Python 2.7 and Python 2.6 results.

Answer (score 0):

When you write something to a file and read from the same file, the contents after the end of the file is read. On some operating systems (windows), this leads to rubbish. You have to seek back to 0 to read the file again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work in python 2.6, but I recently had to deal with a similar problem, but I used something like that and it did the trick

> res = text.encode('utf-8', 'replace')

This should do the trick, as error would be replaced with utf-8. I worked for me.